# How to retrieve a list of the YouTube user's playlists more than 25 records. YouTube API v2, C#

Tags: c#, youtube-api

How to  retrieve a list of the  YouTube user's playlists more than 25 records.
YouTube API v2, C#

**What I did :**

```
 Feed<Playlist> userPlaylists = request.GetPlaylistsFeed(youtubeUserID);  
                                 //i.e youtubeUserID = hollywoodlife09
 foreach (Playlist playlistInfo in userPlaylists.Entries) 
 {
    //work with playlist id.
    GetOtherVideosOfThisPlaylistId(playlistEntryUri.Segments[6]);
    //Segments[6] : it contain playlistId , i.e : "LL2rJLq19N0dGrxfib80M_fg"
 }
```

**Problem :**  Its working fine , but here I can get only 25 records of YouTube User's Playlist.. and unable to set Start-index or something for fetching other records with **Feed< Playlist>** .

so, anyone have idea how to get other records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st fetch all PlaylistID then, evryPlaylistID again cron it with youtubeAPI using

```
      try
        {

            YouTubeRequestSettings settings = new YouTubeRequestSettings("YoutubeLibrary", DeveloperKey);
            settings.Timeout = 120000;
            int start = 1;
            int maxResult = 50;
            int totalVideosCroned = 0;
            var videosLimit=5; //how many max playlistID want ?? add here
            if (videosLimit < maxResult)
            {
                maxResult = videosLimit;
            }
            YouTubeRequest request = new YouTubeRequest(settings);

            do
            {
                totalVideosCroned += maxResult;
                string uri = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/";

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(youtubeID))
                {
                    uri += youtubeID  +"/playlists";

                    uri += "?key=" + DeveloperKey + "&start-index=" + start + "&max-results=" + maxResult;
                    //handle Playlist not found issue // use code for handling URL data 
                    string reponse = GetHttpResponseForPlayList(uri);



                        start += maxResult;

                        var videoEntryUrl = new Uri(uri);
                        Feed<Video> videoFeed = request.Get<Video>(videoEntryUrl);
                        foreach (Video entry in videoFeed.Entries)
                        {
                            string playlistId = Regex.Replace(entry.Id, ".*:playlist:", "");
                            //Do cron youtube with playlist ID now

                   CronPlaylistYoutubeVideo(playlistId);
                            totalVideosCroned = videosLimit;  // explicitly condition full feel to stop loop .
                        }

                        /*if (videoFeed.Entries.Count() < 50)  // if need to get more playlist records, : i.e if userAccount has 100 playlist then to get all, this should be uncomment
                        {
                            totalVideosCroned = videosLimit;
                        }*

                        /* This code will get 25 playlist records without use of gdata URI
                         * Feed<Playlist> userPlaylists = request.GetPlaylistsFeed(channelfilter.AccountName);
                        foreach (Playlist playlistInfo in userPlaylists.Entries)
                        {
                            Uri playlistEntryUri = new Uri(playlistInfo.Self);
                            CronPlaylistYoutubeVideo(playlistEntryUri.Segments[6], channelfilter, channel, videosLimit);
                            totalVideosCroned = videosLimit; // explicitly stop loop.
                        }*/


                }
                else
                {
                    totalVideosCroned = videosLimit;
                }
            } while (totalVideosCroned < videosLimit);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           //handle it if need..
            return;
        }
```